# Why does the data still exist after I delete the space of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Today, I found a small problem when creating dynamic arrays.

I use the resize () function to change the size of the array. In the resize () function, I created a temporary array "newData", and then I assigned it the new size I wanted. After assigning the value of the initial array "Data" to it, I set

```
Data=newData;
```

At this time, the task of the resize () function has been completed. Before exiting the function, I had a whim and deleted the space of "newData" by

```
delete [] newData;
```

After that, when I output the value of Data [2], I can still output the value.

Now I'm a little confused. "Data" and "newData" should be pointers, right? When I use the statement "Data=newData;", what "Data" points to should become the address space that "newData" points to. If I delete the address space of "newData", shouldn't the space corresponding to "Data" also disappear? Why can I continue to output values?

The following is the complete code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Length = 0;
int* Data;
void resize(int,int *);

int main()
{
  Data = new int[5];//This is the space I allocated for the initial array
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     Data[i] = i;
  Length = 5;//There are five data in the initial array
  int newLength = 10;//I started distributing new sizes to the initial array
  resize(newLength,Data);
  cout << Data[2];//The output is still 2
}

void resize(int newLength,int *Data)
{
  int* newData = new int[newLength];//A temporary array
  for (int i = 0; i <Length; i++)//Move the value of the original array to the temporary array
  {
     newData[i] = Data[i];
  }
  Data = newData;
  delete[] newData;//Delete the space where the temporary array is located
}
```

Comment: Your program has _undefined behavior_, that's all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is to say, this is indeed a wrong writing method, and the data is unstable, right?

Comment: it's not only unstable. @spciyofwolf123 read my answer. You might just as well make your program crash or misbehave in very bad ways. What you programmed is plainly a bug. Also, your function signature makes no sense; `Data` in `resize` is a copy of the pointer you're passing in, not a reference to that pointer, so that `Data = newData;` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: The nature of _undefined behavior_ is that it's ***undefined***. Don't do that, period.

Comment: Yep, what @πάνταῥεῖ said: Computers are awesome in that they can run *any* program. The bad thing is that almost all programs are totally useless, and your job as programmer is to make that omnipotent machine do exactly what you want, and nothing else.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I changed it as you said, and the data really became suitable. thank you

Comment: @spciyofwolf123 what. Nothing about this program should produce *suitable* data?!

Comment: pssst... `std::vector`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number pssst… extended my answer to mention that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found that After adding & to the function shape and adding "delete [] Data;" before the last sentence of the resize function, the output value of Data [2] in the main function is no longer a string of numbers.

Comment: @spciyofwolf123 that is not *suitable* data. Again, you **must not** assume *anything* about that data. Neither how it looks nor how it does not look. The fact that there was the original data there was **not** wrong.

Comment: @spciyofwolf123 the output of code with undefined behavior is meaningless. It can change even if you do not modify the code. It can change when the moon is in a different phase.

Comment: Exactly. Looking at deleted memory has absolutely no information. You cannot infer *anything* from there being the original data. You have **not** fixed your program. You just made it worse, if anything!

Comment: the thing is: Code without undefined behavior has well defined behavior, you get guaranteed by the standard of the language what the program does when you execute it. You do not get that for code with undefined behavior, its more like rolling dice, you might get what you expect, it might even look as if it was reliable and reproducible, but it isnt its just by chance

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You (try to¹) access deleted space; that's what is called *undefined behaviour* in C++: Anything might happen. There might be the original values, the might be some other data you worked on put there, there might be the value `0xdeadcafe` all over the place, your program might crash or cause a fire, delete all files or give an attacker access.

It's undefined, and you found one of the things that might happen.

---

¹ From your question, that was your intent. Luckily, you messed up your `resize` function prototype, and pass in the `Data` pointer by value, not by reference, so that your `Data = newData;` doesn't do anything outside your function. That together with the global variables on top of your files: Maybe revisit what a function is and what scope and pass-by-reference mean!

---

Generally, you're a C++ beginner: cool! That's a good path to be on.
Maybe do less with `new` and `delete`. It's been a while since I used these two, they're becoming a rare pattern in modern C++! C++ can very well (for the most part) be written without these, completely, by using other methods, where your memory allocation and deallocation are linked to objects' lifetimes. And that's way less error-prone, and honestly, easier to understand.
For example, in your use case, instead of your `Data`, `newData`, `new` and `delete` handling, you could have said `std::vector<int> Data(Length);`, have put the values in exactly as you did, and then just called `Data.resize(newLength);`. No need for manually knowing where to delete your memory!

I'm not sure why you're doing this, but you're declaring your variables globally. That's a bad idea from start to finish, so, um, just don't do that: Declare variables in the scope you need them, which would be your `main` function. Maybe someone who has had a very early 1970's copy of some C book confused obsolete C with the C++ you should be taught? I don't know. Global variables are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your advice(´･ᴗ･`). I'm learning about data structures. The teacher assigned a job to create a variable length list. Considering that vector is already an encapsulated data structure, I chose to use ”new” to create it.

Comment: Ah, nice! Yeah, the `std::vector` internally uses `new` internally (or, something equivalent). However, what it does not do is copy over any elements when you're shrinking the vector, and what the most elegant thing is, in data structure, it keeps its own knowledge of the length of its content (and the length of allocated memory, because that can be more than the current length of content). So, if you were tasked with creating a data structure in C++, try to put your pointer to the data, and the current length, in a `class` (or `struct`, same thing), and give it a `.resize` method.

Comment: (hinthint: C++ and other programming languages have `struct` (C & C++) /`class` (C++, Java, Python, …) / `object` (Javascript,…) /… exactly to avoid having some spuriously flying around unstructured global values. That's what it is to design a data structure: define exactly what is part of it, and what isn't. You using global variables here *really* is a problem if the job was to design a data structure!)